# What's wrong going with indexing the lists in python?

Tags: python, numpy

This is not a duplicate question because I wan to know what is wrong in my code rather than to  find alternative solution.

What's wrong going with my code below?
The result is consisting of only 51 but it should also include other elements 30,11,29 from list 'data_B'.

```
import numpy as np

names_A = ['David', 'Mark', 'Brian', 'Michael']
data_A = [4,3,1,2]

names_B = ['Mark', 'David', 'Michael', 'Brian']
data_B = [51,30,11,29]

data = np.array([[4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,3],
                [4,3,3,3,2,2,3,1,3,1],
                [4,2,3,3,2,2,4,1,4,3]])


dats = data.ravel()

results = []
for d in dats:
    nam_A = names_A[data_A == int(d)]
    ##HERE IS THE POTENTIAL ERROR!!!
    dat_B = data_B[names_B == nam_A]
    results.append(dat_B)

print np.array(results).reshape(data.shape)


[[51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51]
 [51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51]
 [51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51]]
```

Answer (score 3):

*What's wrong going with my code below?*

`data_A == int(d)` returns `False/0` as a list could never be equal to  an integer so you get the same thing every time  element `0` of `nam_A` `David`.

Then you use  `dat_B = data_B[names_B == nam_A]` a.k.a `['Mark', 'David', 'Michael', 'Brian'] == "David"` so again that is `False/0` as a list could not be equal to a string so you add element `0` of `data_B`  `51` again and again and again....

I have no idea what the logic of your code is, you create an array, call ravel and don't use the array for anything that a list could not do.